# Passing string array to method and display result (WPF, C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, string, parameter-passing

When I selected folder Im printing this path to my TextBlock (WPF):

```
folderName = dialog.SelectedPath.ToString();
tbArea = "Selected Path: " + dialog.SelectedPath.ToString() + "\r\n";
```

As probably I will use this more then one time, I have created method:

```
 public void addToTextArea(string[] newString)
 {
  tbArea = tbArea + newString + "\r\n";
 }
```

Now Im doing like this:

```
 string[] arr = {"Selected Path", dialog.SelectedPath.ToString()};

 addToTextArea(arr);
```

But as result Im getting this: **System.String[]**.

What is wrong or missing?

Comment: The default `.ToString()` behavior in .NET is to return the full name of the type. So technically nothing is wrong - you just need to tell .NET how to combine the _elements_ of the array into a single `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to join items in an array with some common string in between them, you can use the `string.Join` method (note I'm using `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\r\n` because it's more platform-friendly):

```
public void AddToTextArea(string[] newStrings)
{
    tbArea += string.Join(Environment.NewLine, newStrings) + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

The `string.Join` method takes in a string to conacatenate the items with and then returns a string containing all the items joined with the specified string. A more common example is:

```
int[] items = {1,2,3,4,5};

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", items));

// Output: "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

Note that there is no leading or trailing connecting string (`", "`) added to the list, so in your case we add a newline character to the end.

---

An alternative would be to create an overload that takes in a single string, and then call that method for each item in the string array:

```
public void AddToTextArea(string[] newStrings)
{
    foreach (string newString in newStrings)
    {
        AddToTextArea(newString);
    }
}

public void AddToTextArea(string newString)
{
    tbArea = tbArea + newString + Environment.NewLine;
}
```